# ui router not activating the controller in template context

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a template which would be resolved in `ui-view` as

```
<div class="row login" >
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 " ng-class="offSet">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now The ui router state which resolves this template from templateUrl is

```
 .state('login.register', {
    url: "login/register",
    views: {
        "@": {
            templateUrl: "/Account/Register"
        },
        controller: "loginController"
    }
})
```

And the controller is :

```
ngApp.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
$scope.offSet = "col-lg-offset-3";
$scope.login = function () {
    $state.go('dashboard.home');
   }
}])
```

Now what I want is the `ng-class` should get applied as soon as the template resolves and rendered. But thats not happening . the ng-class is not getting applied if I dont provide ng-controller attribute .

However when I put the ng-controller='loginController' in my template as

```
<div class="row login" ng-controller="loginController">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-6 " ng-class="offSet">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the class gets attached  and I can see the effect on resulting dom.
But as far as ui router documentation says . the controlller gets attached to the dom as soon as the template is resolved .

Any idea why without ng-controller attribute its not working ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, solution here is surprisingly simple. `Controller` belongs to the `view`, in our case to **"named" view**, not to the cluster *views*:

```
.state('login.register', {
    url: "login/register",
    views: {
        "@": {
            templateUrl: "/Account/Register"
            controller: "loginController"     // here it will be used
        },
        //controller: "loginController"       // just skipped
    }
})
```

*In case we'd like to reuse one controller for more named views, we just repeat its definition for each of them...*

Comment: Okay .. so the controller in my code still targets the unnamed views right ? what difference does it make . Cause as far as documentation goes "@" actually targets unnamed views . So still the controller outside which has been mentioned should target the unnmaed view ? According to my understanding ?

Comment: NO no no no no ;) In your case, there is no definition other than "@" no other view is in place. This defintion `views : { "@" : {...` is now representing the ONLY view definition. Any other properties of root *views* are swallowed... does it help?

Comment: okay .. yeah it does . haha . thanks for making it clear . I like your way :)

Comment: Great to see that, sir! Enjoy amazing `UI-Router` ;)